# StackOverflowException when providing dynamic overload

Tags: c#, dynamic, overloading, stack-overflow

I have a long list of method overloads `M(...)`, and I wanted to provide a general method `M(object)` that would invoke the correct overload based on the object's type. Just before I coded a big if-statement for invoking the correct overload, I realized C# 4 has the `dynamic` keyword. So I wrote this:

```
class X
{
    public void M(int x)
    { Console.WriteLine("M(int)"); }

    public void M(long x)
    { Console.WriteLine("M(long)"); }

    // ...20 more overloads of M() here...

    // For if you have an object of an unknown type:
    public void M(dynamic x)
    { M(x); }
}
```

And when I use it correctly everything is fine. However, when I provide a *wrong* type of value, dynamic overload resolution (obviously) recurses to `M(dynamic)`, then tries again, resulting in an infinite recursion and eventually a `StackOverflowException`.

```
X x = new X();
x.M((int)10);               // "M(int)"
x.M((long)10);              // "M(long)"
x.M((object)10);            // "M(int)"
x.M((object)String.Empty);  // StackOverflowException
```

Of course, the `M(dynamic)` overload is technically the same as `M(object)`, so overload resolution will pick the dynamic overload again and again and again...

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Note that dynamic was introduced into C# 4.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way of doing this so that the caller *doesn't* need to do anything is to separate "public method to be called" from "implementation":

```
public void M(dynamic x)
{
    MImpl(x);
}

private void MImpl(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("M(int)");
}

// etc

private void MImpl(object x)
{
    // No more specific overloads matched. Throw some appropriate exception,
    // or take a default action.
}
```

Comment: You mean for each `M(..)` method a corresponding private `MImpl(..)` method, and then let the DLR do overload resolution on `MImpl` instead of `M`?

Comment: @Virtlink: No, you just have a single M method which dispatches dynamically to any number of MImpl methods.

Comment: Statically typed overloading is much faster than dynamic, and provides helpful hints to users, so in most cases I want to simply use static types. Otherwise I wouldn't have made the other overloads public, obviously.

Comment: @Virtlink: In that case you *could* provide `M` overloads which just delegate down to `MImpl` overloads. That would definitely work... but your requirements aren't really clear to be honest. (Especially when you bring performance in, when it isn't mentioned in your question.)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the `M(dynamic)` overload should *not* be provided. To get the same behavior, let instead the caller invoke the method dynamically. Like this:

```
X x = new X();
x.M((int)10);               // "M(int)"
x.M((long)10);              // "M(long)"
x.M((dynamic)10);           // "M(int)"
x.M((dynamic)String.Empty); // RuntimeBinderException
```